# Difference between  and 

Tags: cuneiform, sumerian

Can someone help me understand the difference between these 2 symbols? both mean to kill...

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%92%84%A3

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%92%84%A4

Comment: Those are synonyms. The difference between the symbols is the the number of wedges. Is this the kind of explanation you need? If no, could you specify what exactly you'd like to be explained about those symbols?

Comment: I think just knowing they are synonyms is good enough thank you @YellowSky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gum (
) usually means to beat something to pieces, while gaz (
) means to crush something.

[This glossary](https://cdli.ucla.edu/pubs/cdlp/cdlp0003_20160104.pdf) shows gaz as something similar to gum. They're synonyms.